# How to get an extra parameter value in Select2 via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I bind an extra property to a **Select2** ddl and want to retrieve this property value (**Key**) via jQuery as shown below:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetProjects()
{
    var projects = repository.Projects.Select(m => new ProjectViewModel
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Name = m.Name,
        Key = m.Key //Extra parameter that I want to retrieve using jQuery                
    })
    return Json(projects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I populated the ddl successfully and try to get the Key value besides Name and Id onChange, but no idea how to get it:

**View:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="key" name="Key" value=0 /> 

//I fill the ddl without no problem via Select2 and there is no need to post its code for brevity
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select")

$('#ProjectId').change(function (e) {
        projectId = $(this).val(); // I can get the selected ProjectId value
        debugger;

        //!!! But cannot get the Key value
        var key = $('#ProjectId').select2('data').Key;
}
```

Any idea?

Here is the rendered HTML for Select2:

```
<select class="select2-hidden-accessible" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Proje must be a number." data-val-required="Req" id="ProjectId" name="ProjectId" 
tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">Project A</option></select>

<span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" 
aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-ProjectId-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ProjectId-container" 
title="Project A"><span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span>Project A</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
<b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span>
```

Comment: could you show the rendered html for select2

Comment: @Mir Posted to the question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any key attribute in your select option

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of the problem:

```
<input type="hidden" id="projectPKey" name="ProjectPKey" value=0 /> 

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select" )

projectId.select2({
    //code removed for brevity
    processResults: function (data, page) {
    var newData = [];
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        newData.push({            
            id: item.Id, //id part present in data             
            text: item.Description, //string to be displayed
            key: item.Key //extra parameter(s)
        });
    });
});


var pkey = $('#ProjectId').find(':selected').data().data.key;
$('#projectPKey').val(pkey);
console.log(pkey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

From [here](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats) (useful for those new to Select2, like myself):

> Additional parameters passed in with data objects will be included on
> the data objects that Select2 exposes.

And [here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections) it tells how to retrieve the current selection, which is returned as an array of objects:

> $('#mySelect2').select2('data');

So for the code example of this question, you would retrieve the 'Key' value of current selection like this:

```
var key = ($('#ProjectId').select2('data')[0]).Key;
```